# Xcode storyboard compilation issue for version 6.3

Tags: xcode, compilation, storyboard, popover

I am working on a simple table with custom cell in a View controller (iPad App). I have created a separate popover view controller to add new record to the table (data entry only) and I am trying to use same view controller to edit the row also (the selected row in the table view). The popover view works well for creating the new record. 
But when I created a connection from the table view cell to the same view controller, the compilation fails with following message:

> Interface Builder Storyboard Compilation Error : Couldn't compile
>   connection: IBCocoaTouchOutletConnection:   => anchorView =>
>   IBUITableViewCell: 0x7fad4ca76d70

If I make the connection as PUSH or MODAL, the compilation goes through and I can execute the app.

I wanted to have the Add/Edit record view as a popover as this has only 4 fields. Now it works only if it is push mode. Can you please help me in solving this issue?

Comment: Additional info: I was continuing to work on finding the root cause for this.  In one case, the error does not come - If I remove the Reuse cell identifier this error will go. But in that case I will not be able to show the custom cell contents. I am still trying to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this resolved using the custom segue from the cell to the view controller (popover mode). Following are the steps:

1. Created the custom segue in Storyboard from custom cell to target view controller.
2. Created a new class file subclass of UIStoryboardSegue and linked this to the custom segue in storyboard.
3. Used the segue id in prepareForSegue (as usual).

Below is the code I used in the custom segue class:

class myCellSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

```
override func perform() {
    var sourceVC: UIViewController = self.sourceViewController as! UIViewController
    var destVC: UIViewController = self.destinationViewController as! UIViewController

    destVC.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    destVC.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(600, 500)

    let popoverPresentationVC = destVC.popoverPresentationController
    popoverPresentationVC?.sourceView = destVC.view
    popoverPresentationVC?.permittedArrowDirections = .Down

    // ==== View parameters ========
    destVC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()

    sourceVC.view.addSubview(destVC.view)
    sourceVC.presentViewController(destVC, animated: false, completion: nil)


}
```

}

BTW - we can use one custom segue for multiple segue connections.